# For ideals $I, J$ does $I\cdot J= I \cap J$ imply that $I$ and $J$ are co prime

Tags: commutative-algebra

We are working in a commutative ring $R$ with ideals $I, J$. We always have that $IJ\subset (I\cap J)(I+J)$. If $I$ and $J$ are coprime then we get that $IJ=I\cap J$.

Is the converse true? If not can you give a counterexample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse is obviously false (in general): take $I=J=\{0\}$.

Also note that the inclusion is
$$
IJ\supset (I\cap J)(I+J)
$$
from which follows, when $I+J=R$, that $IJ\supset I\cap J$. The inclusion $IJ\subset I\cap J$ holds for any two ideals.